# Android EditText view being interpreted as ImageView?

Tags: android, imageview, android-edittext

In my app, I am creating a dialog, like so:

```
dialogview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.registration_dialog, null);
dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
dialog.setView(dialogview);
```

And then, assigning several views to variables:

```
    username = (EditText)dialogview.findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText)dialogview.findViewById(R.id.password);
    confirm = (EditText)dialogview.findViewById(R.id.confirm);
    rememberme = (CheckBox)dialogview.findViewById(R.id.rememberme);
    autologin = (CheckBox)dialogview.findViewById(R.id.autologin);
```

All the variables are appropriately defined, before my onCreate:

```
private EditText username;
private EditText password;
private CheckBox rememberme;
private CheckBox autologin;
private EditText confirm;
```

When I try and create the dialog, however, the app crashes. I checked the eclipse debugger, which reports the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
```

on the line

```
confirm = (EditText)dialogview.findViewById(R.id.confirm);
```

The XML definition for the confirm field is as follows:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/confirm"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:inputType="textPassword">
</EditText>
```

I am beyond confused - there isn't even any ImageViews inside my dialoglayout. Is this some strange glitch? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R.java file needs to be refreshed. Try to Clean your project and compile again. \

Comment: Oh wow, thanks! I didn't expect it would be so simple - especially since there never was an ImageView, I wouldn't have guessed it just needed a refresh. I'll mark this as accepted after the 5-minute limitation is up.